# Any chance for alter system settings form via hook_form_alter?

Tags: 7, forms

I would like to create module based on other custom module. One thing that will be nice to able to do is to alter module settings form fields. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Most common way is to use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().

Comment: Don't forget to add dependencies in your module to other custom module.

Answer (score 3):

You can alter any forms using [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). `$form`, `$form_states`, and `$form_id` are the parameters it gets.

Do not forget to add the following line, at the end of your `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

```php
    $form = system_settings_form($form);
```

If you don't want to add the "Save configuration" button, you have to add your custom callback submit with `$form['#submit'][] = '_my_callback_form_submit';` and use code similar to the following one.

```php
function _my_callback_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  variable_set('my_variable_name', $form_state['values']['my_variable_name']);
}
```